# wierdness using tee: can anyone explain?

Tags: bash, tee

I sometimes want to output the contents of a pipe in the middle (don't we all?).

I generally do it like this (yes, I know there are other, probably better, ways):

```
terminal=$(tty) 
echo hello world |tee $terminal|awk '{print $2, $1}'
```

which outputs

```
hello world
world hello
```

Which is fine and in all respects lovely.

Except that I'd *really* like to do it without creating the $terminal variable.
Easy, you say, just replace '`tee $terminal`'   with '`tee $(tty)`' in the pipe, and no need for a variable? Right?

Wrong.

```
echo hello world |tee $(tty)|awk '{print $2, $1}'
```

outputs

```
world hello
```

In other words, my output from the middle of the pipe has been swallowed.

Now I accept that this is definitely a first world problem, but it annoys me and I'd like to know why the second solution doesn't work.

Anyone?

Comment: +1 for "first world problem" and good question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your system supports it, you can access the current terminal directly with `/dev/tty`:

```
echo hello world | tee /dev/tty | awk '{print $2, $1}'
```

(The file is available in Linux and Mac OS X, at any rate.)

The `tty` command returns the name of the file connected to standard input, which may not necessarily be a terminal. In your pipe, it's the "file" associated with the standard output of the preceding command.

Comment: Tested and works on raspbian, netbsd, CentOS; so it should be good for most use.

Comment: Ah.yes. That makes complete sense. I should have known that.(o//O). (according to wikipedia thats an emoticon for embarrassed). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `tee` with Process Substitution if supported on your system:

```
echo hello world | tee  >(awk '{print $2, $1}')
```

The line sometimes comes too late, so you may need to add `; sleep .01` at the end if needed.

Or you can use the standard error for reporting:

```
echo hello world | tee >(cat >&2) |  awk '{print $2, $1}'
```